# Reacting to an HTML element that is created after the initial DOM was

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, dom

I have a Bootstrap dropdown button that is filled like the following:

```
<ul id="brandselection" class="dropdown-menu">
  <li><a href='#'>Brand1</a></li>
  <li><a href='#'>Brand2</a></li>
</ul>
```

Then I have the following JS code to dynamically create and fill a second dropdown button depending on the selection of the first:

```
$(function() {
  $("#brandselection li").click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    $("#model").load("getModelsUL.php?brand=" + encodeURI($(this).text()));
  });
});
```

The resulting button code is basically the same as the one described above - and is created correctly.

But then, I use the exact same JS function (only the id of the `div` being different) to react to a click on the second button - and it doesn't even enter the function.

I assume it is a problem with the DOM not being considered, since the second button was created after the initial DOM, but I don't know how to handle it correctly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's just a small change to make this work.  Change your code to this...

```
$(function() {
    $("#brandselection").on("click", "li", function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        $("#model").load("getModelsUL.php?brand=" + encodeURI($(this).text()));
    });
});
```

That attaches the click handler to `#brandselection` but only fires the handler when the selector matches the second parameter of `li`.

This is event delegation and is for exactly this type of scenario, where you want to code event handlers and forget about them, for a DOM that will change in the future.

Comment: The answer solved my problem halfway. Actually, I created the botton itself dynamically, since I only wanted it to be displayed when the selection in the first dropdown was made. That didn't work, also not with the solution described above. I had to create the referenced item at the very beginning and could then dynamically change its content.